# How do i know if a branch is shortlisted or no in GIT

Tags: git

I am writing a script to see if a if a particular branch is shortlisted in GIT. Is there a way for me to identify if my branch is shortlisted?

Comment: What's the definition of a *shortlisted branch*?

Answer (score 0):

I guess by "shortlisted branch" you're referring to git tags.

You've got several ways to achieve what you want. First, you can know which branch contains a specific tag:

```
$ git branch --contains <your-tag>
```

Another way that could help you is to start by the tag, to look if it contains a specific commit:

```
$ git branch --contains <your-commit>
```

Let's say you want to know if your `develop` branch is tagged somewhere:

- retrieve the last commit hash of the `develop` branch
- check for tags referring to this commit

```
$ git log -n 1 develop
$ git tag --contains 47de457061023423423428ae6e38603863f6f750
```

If the output list is empty, your `develop` branch wasn't tagged. Otherwise, you'll get the list of related tags.

---

**The quick way for the current branch:**

```
$ git tag --contains HEAD
```